# meteor.js & mongoDB - query with multiple fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

**CONTEXT**

I am trying to create a search functionality allowing users to fill in multiple fields, submit, and see a list of matching items from one collection. I do this using a form on the front end, which updates session variables on back-end, which are then passed as query to a mongodb collection.

**HOW IT SHOULD WORK**

If a user submits a venue size, then venues of that size are shown. If only a location is typed in, then venues within that location are shown. If both a size and a location are submitted, then venues that match both criteria are shown.

**HOW IT ACTUALLY WORKS**

If nothing is filled in, pressing search yields all items in the collection. Submitting both location and size yields venues that match both criteria. However, **filling in only one field and leaving the other empty yields nothing in results**. I'm wondering why this might be - it's almost as if the query is searching for a field that literally contains ''... but then why don't I see this behavior when leaving both fields empty? Help much appreciated!

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
//Search Form Helper
Template.managevenues.helpers({
  venue: function () {

    var venueNameVar = Session.get('venueNameVar');
    var venueLocationVar = Session.get('venueLocationVar');

    if(venueNameVar || venueLocationVar){
        console.log(venueNameVar);
        console.log(venueLocationVar);

        return Venues.find({
            venueName: venueNameVar,
            'venueAddress.neighbourhood': venueLocationVar
    });
    } else {
        return Venues.find({});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in your query

```
Venues.find({
        venueName: venueNameVar,
        'venueAddress.neighbourhood': venueLocationVar
});
```

If you don't have one of your `vars` set it will look like this...

```
{
   venueName: undefined,
   'venueAddress.neighbourhood':'someVal'
}
```

So it would match any venue that doesn't have a name and is in some neighborhood.

A better approach would be to only set query criteria if there's a value to search...

```
var query = {};
if(Session.get('venueNameVar')) {
   query.venueName = Session.get('venueNameVar');
}
if(Session.get('venueLocationVar') {
   query.venueAddress = {
       neighbourhood : Session.get('venueLocationVar');
   }
}
return Venues.find(query);
```

I think this will work a bit better for you!