# meteor.js & collection2 - how to query sub-schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2

**QUERY**

I'm trying to query a collection using the code below, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232241/meteor-js-mongodb-query-with-multiple-fields). It works fine for venueName but not for venueLocation - I'm guessing it must be something to do with the fact that it's a sub-schema, and I'm not writing the query properly.

```
    var query = {};
    if(Session.get('venueNameVar')) {
       query.venueName = Session.get('venueNameVar')
    }
    if(Session.get('venueLocationVar')){
       query.venueAddress = {
       neighbourhood : Session.get('venueLocationVar')
    }
    return Venues.find(query);
```

**COLLECTIONS**

My main schema and sub-schema work well across the app so far:

```
//MAIN SCHEMA
Schema.Venues = new SimpleSchema({
    venueAddress: {
        type: Schema.VenueAddress,
        optional: true
    }, [...]

//SUB-SCHEMA
Schema.VenueAddress = new SimpleSchema({
    neighbourhood: {
        type: String,
        max: 100,
        optional: true
    }, [...]
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

1. Using `Schema.venueAddress.neighbourhood = Sesssion.get('venueLocationVar')` - does not work
2. Changing VenueAddress --> venueAddress - does not work
3. Using square brackets, equals instead of colon, etc. - does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try to do `query['venueAddress.neighbourhood'] = someVal` im not positive that minimongo can search using objects

In other words you have to use `dot notation` when doing queries

Comment: You got it Patrick - I used your code and it works flawlessly. Could you clarify why you used `query['venue...` instead of `query.['venue...` I'm not that familiar with dot notation.

Comment: So an JSON `object` is kind of like an `[]` except your index has a alphanumeric value. therefor you can access `query.something` via `query['something']`. With mongodb you use what is refered to as `dot notation` to look up things in the DB that are embedded your can read more on it [https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/document/#dot-notation](here). To answer your question why not to use `query.['venue...` that is because the syntax is invalid. You can only look up values using `object.key` or `object['key']`